# why is adding padding causing this to expand

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add padding to a box via:

```
.p-box-header{
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: left;
  width: $p-box-width;
  padding: 0px 0px 0xp 20px;
}
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

The 'Food' header is adding 20px to it's width. This didn't happen in box below. Why is this happening and how can I prevent?

thx

Comment: `padding: 0px 0px 0xp 20px;` ? The value is wrong, change `xp` to `px`, it should look like this `padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;` and then try.

Comment: CSS uses the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box_model), which means that the padding area extends the content area. To add 20px of padding while keeping the total width of the element constant, you will need to subtract 20px from the `width` property.

Comment: hmm... so the bottom piece 'my new header' has padding but this is inside a box that is set at 300px. I've probably just been doing it this way without thinking about it. So there's no way to fixing a box at 300px and then adding padding. Could I margin a span on the text for 'Food'?

Comment: Yes, a span should work with either margin or padding. Will the 'Food' text ever be longer than 280px?

Comment: no, shouldn't be longer. thx

Comment: added a span for internal piece per comment above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** : You wrote "0xp" and not "0px". If this doesn't solved your problem, then read the following.

You should take a look at a CSS3 property called **box-sizing**.

This forces the browser to render the box with the specified width and height, and place the border and padding inside the box.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

More infos here : http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ and it's available since IE8 ([CanIUse - Box-sizing](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing))

Comment: ughh.... adding prefixes; i appreciate but getting a headache just thinking about it

Comment: I agree. Just give it a try, hope it helps.

Comment: You'll probably have to set this property on the 'new header' row too or the borders might not line up.

Comment: so this does look like it works but what a headache. I've been doing front-end html for a while but hate stuff like this